# How to add tooltip for a item or cell of a vaadin table

Tags: tooltip, vaadin

I noticed that vaadin 6.7.0 beta1 supports to add tooltip for row/cell of a table. However, I did not find any example how to add it.
Is there anybody who can provide some sample?

Comment: I don't believe that the code for tool tips is currently in the 6.7.0-beta1 jar thats available. I to am interested in this, and I down loaded the jar. The info given in bug http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/5414 suggests what the methods should be, but they don't seem to be present

Answer (score 9):

Use code as below:

```
table.setItemDescriptionGenerator(new ItemDescriptionGenerator() {                             
public String generateDescription(Component source, Object itemId, Object propertyId) {
    if(propertyId == null){
        return "Row description "+ itemId;
    } else if(propertyId == COLUMN1_PROPERTY_ID) {
        return "Cell description " + itemId +","+propertyId;
    }                                                                       
    return null;
}}
```

Comment: It seems that this is only working for non editable tables. If make my table editable the tooltip/description disapears.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this by setting a formfieldfactory. Here you could return a button that only loooks like text with styling CSS. This will let you set a caption on the button. This is obviously a ugly hack. [More info about buttons and links in vaadin](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#ButtonLink).

```
table.setTableFieldFactory(new TableFieldFactory() {

            // container is the datasource
            // item is the row
            // property  is the column
            //
            @Override
            public Field createField(Container container, Object itemId, Object propertyId, Component uiContext) {

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add tooltpis (setDescription) to a row/cell nativly - not yet!
It is already in there issue tracker but don't know when they will implement this feature