# Tooltip for Vaadin Table column header

Tags: java, vaadin7

Can I add a tooltip to a column header in a Vaadin [Table](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html)?

## Motivation

Table columns are often abbreviated to fit the width of their rows’ content. It would be nice for the user if the full-length version the column title could be presented as a tooltip.

For buttons and labels and such, I can call `setDescription` to specify text for an automatic tooltip. Is there some way to do this for a Table header?

## Similar Discussions

I found [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558119/how-to-add-tooltip-for-a-item-or-cell-of-a-vaadin-table) for adding tooltips to rows and cells.

I found this [Vaadin Forum posting](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/310923/3372639) on hacking some HTML for tooltip on an icon in a table header. But I want just a simple tooltip on a header, and have not found such information.

I have read the [Table page](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html) in the [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book).

Assuming no such feature is available, I have filed [this feature request # 14419](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/14419).

Comment: Same Question for Grid instead of Table: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411106

Comment: Feature added to Grid in Vaadin 8.4.0. https://github.com/vaadin/framework/pull/10489