# Description tooltips for Vaadin Grid header cells

Tags: java, vaadin

I'd like to define descriptions for Grid header cells, similarly to how `AbstractComponent.setDescription(String description)` works (i.e. tooltip shown on mouse hover). As the Grid doesn't support this in itself, I tried adding a `Label` component into the header cell, and then use `setDescription()` on the label. I can get the info tooltip working like this, but the downside is that clicking on the label component doesn't trigger sorting. If I want to sort the column, I need to click the header cell on the really narrow area that's left between the right edge of the label component and the column border, where the sorting indicator will be shown. If you look at the screenshot below, the highlighted area is the label component, and in order to trigger sorting, the user needs to click on the space on the right side of the component.

[image: Example Grid]

Is there a better way to apply descriptions to header cells than the one I described? And if not, is there a way to make the sorting work properly when the header cell contains a Component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Feature added to Vaadin 8.4.0

Feature added to Grid in Vaadin 8.4.0.

Ticket:
https://github.com/vaadin/framework/pull/10489

Release notes:
https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.4/8.4.0/release-notes.html

> Grid headers and footers now support tooltips.

Comment: i can not find examples. How to get the HeaderCell Object?

Comment: This seems to have got lost somewhere on the way to Vaadin 24.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the answer from kukis, I managed to come up with a simpler solution that doesn't require any JavaScript. Instead of adding a Label component into the header cell, I'm adding a div element manually with `StaticCell.setHtml()`, and setting the title attribute on it:

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    Grid grid = new Grid();
    grid.addColumn("to");
    grid.addColumn("the");
    grid.addColumn("moon");

    Grid.HeaderRow headerRow = grid.getDefaultHeaderRow();
    headerRow.getCell("to").setHtml("<div title='Hello world'>to</div>");
    headerRow.getCell("the").setHtml("<div title='Hello world 2'>the</div>");
    headerRow.getCell("moon").setHtml("<div title='Hello world 3'>moon</div>");

    grid.addRow("1","2","3");
    grid.addRow("d","v","w");
    grid.addRow("g","s","h");

    setContent(new VerticalLayout(grid));
}
```

Comment: Upvote. I had same issue as you and have therefore created an [Enhancement ticket](https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/19637#ticket) for this feature as I believe it is fairly low hanging fruit to implement in Vaadin core. Until then your workaround will do the job. Thanks.

Comment: Decent workaround but native browser tooltips don't look great.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but IMO it's good enough until the Vaadin team provides a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since Grid doesn't support it by itself you can always use JavaScript to achieve desired behaviour. SSCCE:

```
private final String SCRIPT;
{
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append("var grid = document.getElementById('mygrid');\n");
    b.append("var child = grid.getElementsByClassName('v-grid-tablewrapper')[0];\n");
    b.append("child = child.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild;\n");
    b.append("child.childNodes[0].title='Hello world';\n");
    b.append("child.childNodes[1].title='Hello world 2';\n");
    b.append("child.childNodes[2].title='Hello world 3';\n");
    SCRIPT = b.toString();
}

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    Grid grid = new Grid();
    grid.addColumn("to");
    grid.addColumn("the");
    grid.addColumn("moon");
    grid.addRow("1","2","3");
    grid.addRow("d","v","w");
    grid.addRow("g","s","h");
    grid.setId("mygrid");
    setContent(layout);
    layout.addComponent(grid);
    JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(SCRIPT);
}
```

Another possibility would be to develop your own Grid in GWT based on the Grid provided by Vaadin Team but it is a way higher cost approach.

Another solution would be to, as you have tried, put label in a column and propagate the label-clicked-event to the Grid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I managed to find a simpler solution, but your answer gave me the idea for it, so +1

Answer (score 1):

I use my own utillity finction:

```
public static Grid setHeaderCellDescription(Grid grid, int rowIndex, String property, String description) {
    Grid.HeaderCell cell;
    String cellHeader = "<span title=\"%s\">%s</span>";
    cell = grid.getHeaderRow(rowIndex).getCell(property);
    cell.setHtml(String.format(cellHeader, description, cell.getText()));
    return grid;
}
```

You may add some additional checks if need (existing of cell and row number).

Or other variant - instead setHtml use cetComponent.

```
Grid.HeaderCell cell = grid.getHeaderRow(rowIndex).getCell(property);
Label newLabel = new Label(cell.getText());
newLabel.setDescription(description);
cell.setComponent(newLabel);
```

Answer (score 1):

Update for Vaadin 23: you can use your own `Component` as a column header with this method: `com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid.Column#setHeader(com.vaadin.flow.component.Component)`.

So you can use e.g. a `Span` with a title:

```
Span headerComponent = new Span();
headerComponent.setText("Your header text");
headerComponent.getElement().setProperty("title", "Your tooltip text");
column.setHeader(headerComponent);
```